Creating a Search Kit Contact Summary Tab for activities, how do you only display activities of a specific activity type for the contact being viewed?
Civi version 5.71.2
Wordpress 6.4.3
I have only been successful at either getting all activities of the specific type for all contacts in the system viewed on the specific contact page, or, the correct activities for the viewed contact, but when any individual activity check box is clicked, every check is filled ( which I definitely don't want it to do. I have tried many combinations of different filter fields in form builder, values in the Search for page, etc. I even tried a search on contacts instead of activities.
I have made many tabs like this for displaying relationships but but I haven't been able to adapt the approach there with activities.
Screenshots are of the Search Kit 'Search For' page, Select Fields, and the Formbuilder filter page.




It sounds like you are trying to add a tab to the contact summary screen to show activities? The latest version of CiviCRM includes the Admin UI extension which has just such a search all ready for you to use.
Due to a performance issue reported on some sites, the tab is disabled by default, but after enabling the CiviCRM Admin UI extension you can visit the "Form Builder" screen, edit the "Activities" search form, and enable "Placement" as "Contact Summary Tab". This will give you a working contact summary tab to show activities, and you can then clone it & tweak & edit the associated SearchKit search criteria to suit your needs.
